# Preference bundle icon for theos tweak

Tags: objective-c, settings, bundle, preference, theos

possibly an easy answer to this.? 
I have a theos built tweak with a preference bundle displayed in the settings app. 
This allows me to activate / deactivate my tweak.

My question is, how do you put an icon on the main settings app list along side the title.
I can put an icon by the switch, but thats it.

I have not included any code as the preference bundle is working, it just doesn't have an icon.

Comment: You have to put an icon called `<MyBundleName>.png` (and a @2x Retina variation thereof as well) into `/Library/PreferenceLoader/Preferences(/MyBundleName)`, where MyBundleName is of course your bundle name. The last path component may be omitted depending on what kind of preference bundle you use (a simple "throw all files into Preferences" approach vs. a proper bundle).

Comment: Thank you this helped in a round about way.

Answer (score 0):

The default way to do this is to drag your icon named `icon.png` into `/Resources/`.
If you want, you can rename it by editing `icon` entry in your  `/layout/Library/PreferenceLoader/Preferences/<yourbundlename>.plist` file.